# How do we pass array of strings to another function in c++ and how do we access each string in the called function

Tags: c++, arrays

While passing an array of strings to another function by reference, how do i print the values(strings) in the called function one by one and what is the type of argument that needs to be declared in the called function's input parameters.

Comment: I assume you're talking about C-style arrays, and not the [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) class? Then remember that arrays decays to pointers, so in a sense they are already passed as a kind of reference (functions receive a pointer to the first element).

Comment: Some detail wouldn't hurt. Couldn't you show your code, and _precisely_ define your requirements? You'll find that precision is crucial in our field.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an array by reference like this:

```
template <int N>
void foo(string (&arr)[N])
{
  arr[0] = "a";
  arr[1] = "b";
  /// Do other stuff with arr
}
```

Now you can simply use `arr` like a regular array. The template parameter `N` is needed is an array of size `i` and size `j`, are distinct types when `i!=j`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void output_function(string str[])
```

and use str as normal array.

Comment: The `SIZE` parameter is superfluous since arrays just get decayed to pointer in function arguments. This definition will accept `string` arrays of any size.

Comment: I mentioned SIZE as max size like `#define SIZE 500` anyways i removed it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
void Func(const std::string* stringArr, int arraySize) {
  for ( int n = 0; n < arraySize; ++n ) {
     const std::string& sz = stringArr[n];
  }
}


std::string array[10];
Func(array, 10); // here array decays to pointer to its first element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string getConcatenate(string arr[], int size)
{
    string concatenate;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        concatenate += arr[i];
        if (i != size - 1)
            concatenate += " ";
    }
    return concatenate;
}
int main()
{
    string balance[6] = { "This", "is", "an", "example", "string", "array" };
    string sentence;
    sentence = getConcatenate(balance, 6);
    cout << "Concatenated value is: " << sentence.c_str() << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This example illustrates, sending string as array and returning string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some flexibility in how you define an "array of strings" I suggest you use standard containers.

If your "array" is of fixed size use a `std::array`, otherwise use `std::vector`:

```
void doSomethingWithAnArray(const std::array<std::string, 5>& strings);
void doSomethingWithAVector(const std::vector<std::string>& strings);
```

Then one way to access each string in the container is to use a ranged-based for loop. For example:

```
for (auto& str : strings)
    std::cout << str << " ";
std::cout << "\n";
```